# Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've encountered following error message whenever I've tried most of solutions related to that message. Please let me know how to fix it. I've just clone source of https://github.com/davideast/hnpwa-firebase/ and deploy to my firebase account.

I've already installed `npm install` inside `functions` folder.

My NodeJS version is v7.0.0

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: running predeploy script.

> functions@ build /Users/user/Documents/Projects/firebase/hnpwa-firebase/functions
> tslint -p tslint.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc

typeof-compare is deprecated. Starting from TypeScript 2.2 the compiler includes this check which makes this rule redundant.

WARNING: /Users/user/Documents/Projects/firebase/hnpwa-firebase/functions/src/index.ts[1, 13]: 'functions' is declared but its value is never read.

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing dist/server directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'firebase-functions'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "5.4.0",
  "firebase-functions": "0.7.0"
}
```

I've found solution that we're about to upgrade both dependencies `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` as follow.

Answer (score 8):

Try to install with the -g or save-dev argument.

```
npm install -g firebase-functions

npm install --save-dev firebase-functions

npm install firebase-functions
```

this pretty much fixes all of my problems with not finding modules. :D

Comment: I've tried already inside `root` folder and inside `functions` folder. it didn't work though.